# Is it possible to encrypt and decrypt files in flutter?

Tags: encryption, flutter

Can we encrypt and decrypt files in flutter?

I am working on application where i can decrypt and encrypt a file. For example an mp4 format file is already in an encrypted format i need to decrypt the file and show it in my application.
If so please share the code.

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_secure_storage check this

Comment: Which cipher is the file encrypted in? How are you going to get the encryption key?

Comment: Any format is acceptable as long as it can be encrypted and decypted @Richard Heap

Comment: @Deepak did u solve your Problem? if yes how it is?

Comment: @Joe Sorry Joe haven't been able to solve the problem worked on other things

Comment: It seems that there are helpful tutorials I've found online. Have you been able to bump through [this blog](https://www.yahaloms.com/flutter-encryption-of-stored-data/) and this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8GUYpzqT2PQ)? I think it's what you are looking. If you happen to encounter any problem along the way, could you provide at least [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Perform File encryption with Flutter and Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58324907/how-to-perform-file-encryption-with-flutter-and-dart)